# Using token from Connect-AZAccount on Intune Graph calls

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

So, after years consuming valuable information from StackOverflow this is my first question!

I used part of a code I found when researching as I start to move away from App Secrets in Graph API and prepare to use Managed Identities.
It successfully authenticate and generate the token when running locally(haven't tested anything on Azure Automation yet as this would be the PoC) but it will not work for everything in Graph, it works when querying AD Users and Groups but not on anything else, it seems it is not getting all the scopes the accounts has access to although the account is global admin.

**This part will check if you are using Managed Identity or prompt for login**

```
#Requires -Modules @{ ModuleName="Az.Accounts"; ModuleVersion="2.7.0" } , @{ ModuleName="Az.Resources"; ModuleVersion="5.1.0" }

Param(
    [Switch]$nonInteractive
)

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
$res = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

if(!$Global:AZConnection){
    try{
        if($nonInteractive){
            Write-Output "Logging in with MI"
            $Null = Connect-AzAccount -Identity -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Output "Logged in as MI"
        }else{
            Write-Output "Logging in to Azure AD"
            $Global:AZConnection = Connect-AzAccount -Force -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Output "Logged in to Azure AD with $($Global:AZConnection.Context.Account.id)"
        }
    }catch{
        Throw $_
    }
}
```

**After this it will get the context and authenticate against graph.microsoft.com & graph.windows.net to get both tokens.**

**It will also prepare the headers to be used on WebRequests**

```
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext

$graph = ([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Always, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com"))
$graphToken = $graph.AccessToken

$AAD = ([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net"))
$aadToken = $AAD.AccessToken

$HeadersGraph = @{
            'Content-Type'  = "application\json"
            'Authorization' = "Bearer $graphToken" 
}

$HeadersAAD = @{
            'Content-Type'  = "application\json"
            'Authorization' = "Bearer $aadToken" 
}
```

**Trying to use the token to query user or group information will work**

```
$UserData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/Users" -Method GET -Headers $HeadersGraph

$GroupData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/Users" -Method GET -Headers $HeadersGraph
```

**But if I try to query any Intune or SharePoint URI it will give me:**

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

```
$deviceData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices" -Method GET -Headers $HeadersGraph

$SharepointData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites" -Method GET -Headers $HeadersGraph
```

**I can use these Tokens to authenticate on other modules but I was trying to avoid it and keep everything on Graph web requests**

```
#This also works
$Intune = Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $graphToken
$AzureAD = Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id
```

Does anyone know of any resource principal that I can authenticate that would give me a valid token to make calls to SharePoint and Intune?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're aware that this is a permission issue and not a token issue.

I have no solution for your problem. I just want to let you know, that nowadays there is an easier way to get Graph Access tokens (since you are already using the Az.Accounts module).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azaccesstoken

Comment: Hi Andreas,

Thanks for replying

I was not aware of this commands as I was always used to do the everything in web requests, first time using the Az.Accounts module.

I realised it is permissions when I opened pasted the token on https://jwt.io and could see that the only scopes granted were "AuditLog.Read.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All email openid profile". I can see that there is some people asking for then to implement the scope on Get-AzAccessToken, so lets wait and see