# How to access MFA information of users in azure tenant using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, graph-explorer

I would like to access MFA information about users using their UPN but I can't seem to figure out how I can allow permissions programmatically to access their MFA information on azure tenant.

The code below is what I have right now:

```
    $userUPN = "xx.xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"

    $userObjectId = (Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName $userUPN).Id

    $graphApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$($userObjectId)/authentication/methods"

    $accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://graph.microsoft.com).Token

    $responsee = $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphApiUrl -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken" } -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop
```

The error I get:

`"accessDenied, request authorization failed"`

I am able to access MFA information by using graph explorer and send a HTTPS request because it allows me to consent to the permissions. I have attached a screenshot below to show the permissions:

[image]

How can I consent to permissions using powershell so I can access the MFA in my ide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Note** that: When you generate access token using **`Get-AzAccessToken`** permissions like "*AuditLog.Read.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All email openid profile*" only are granted by Microsoft Graph in advance.

[image]

- If the client id is Azure PowerShell, then you cannot generate access token for the scope like `https://graph.microsoft.com/UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All`. Refer this [**GitHub blog**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/14085#issuecomment-1121104355) by Dingmeng Xue.
- You can make use of Microsoft Graph PowerShell module or `Connect-AzAccount` to perform the action.

Create an Azure AD application and grant API permission:

[image]

Now use the below PowerShell script to **Connect-AzAccount using Service principal** and fetch the details:

```
$azureAplicationId ="ClientID"
$azureTenantId= "TenantID"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "ClientSecret" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal 

$userUPN = "user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"

$userObjectId = (Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName $userUPN).Id

$graphApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$($userObjectId)/authentication/methods"

$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://graph.microsoft.com).Token

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphApiUrl -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken" } -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop

$responseJson = $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

Write-Output $responseJson
```

[image]

**Otherwise** make use of Microsoft Graph PowerShell module.

**References:**

[Support user specified permission on ResourceURI by dingmeng-xue · Pull Request #18080 · Azure/azure-powershell · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/pull/18080)

[azure - Using token from Connect-AZAccount on Intune Graph calls - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352866/using-token-from-connect-azaccount-on-intune-graph-calls) by Andy Brunner